# Problem starting up mySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1045, sql-grant

I just downloaded PHP and I tried running mySQL with the command:

```
C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.2i\mySQL\bin\mysql.exe
```

And I got the error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Acess denied for user 'ODBC'@localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I found a solution online with linux, but I'm running vista on this machine and have no clue what all of that meant. Please help, I'm tired of using the school's terminals.

Comment: Do you have a MySQL database server running on your local machine first?

Comment: I have easyPHP running... I just downloaded it

Answer (score 1):

It means one of three likely things.

1. you need to either  create a new user in mysql with the password you are using
2. set the password of the "ODBC" user to what you are using
3. grant permission to the host you are attempting to connect from, in this case localhost

Without more information to your specific setup it will be very difficult to answer with more accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried supplying the username to the command, for example:

```
C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.2i\mySQL\bin\mysql.exe -u root
```

?

Comment: This should work. Looks like trying to connect with a default user which happens to be a non existing one.

Comment: And how exactly do I fix this?

Comment: Bear in mind, I haven't ever used mySQL before, this will be my first time if (I can configure it properly)

Comment: There are users in the MySQL database. You need to specify the user you want to connect as. The super MySQL account is the one named root.

In EasyPHP, (from what I read), they don't have a default user password.

Comment: Try the same command as you've done before but add '-u root' to the end. When you are requested for a password just press return because the default password is blank. One you are logged in then you can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Check the manual  [Connecting to and Disconnecting from the Server](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting-disconnecting.html)